# SQL Server DOUBLE keyword

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

There is a reserved keyword `DOUBLE` in SQL Server, but I know that it's not a data type (other languages' double is `float` or `real` in SQL Server); does anyone know why this is a keyword?

I've tried to use it in SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 and I cannot use it as a data type nor a function and I cannot find any info in MSDN pages; only that it is a reserved keyword and it isn't a data type.

Comment: You most probably don't want to use double (or float or real) anyway: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: We usually use DECIMAL in SQL Server, but sometimes we're limited from third party Databases that use floats instead. Asking for DOUBLE was only to know why it was reserved keyword :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually part of the `DOUBLE PRECISION` type, synonym of `float(53)`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx